# PHP and html tags

Tags: php, html, string-parsing

Trying to do some web scraping but having trouble understanding how php parses html tags.  I'm currently not at my web server so I am testing the code online.
At http://phptester.net/ my code is this:

```
<?php
$start = "<title>";
$end = "</title>";
$data = "<title>this is a test </title>";
echo $start . " " . $end . " " . "<br>";
echo $data . "<br>";
echo strlen($start) . "<br>";
echo htmlspecialchars($data) . "<br>";
$data = stristr(htmlspecialchars($data), htmlspecialchars($start));
$data = substr(htmlspecialchars($data), strlen($start));

if($data===false){
    echo 'string not found';
}
else{
    echo $data;
}
```

Now a few sample inputs and outputs.

```
Input  
  $start="<title>"
  $end="</title>"
Output
  (blank line)
  (blank line)
  7
  <title>this is a test </title>
  ;title&gt;this is a test &lt;/title&gt;

Input
  $start=&lt;title&gt;
  $end=&lt;/title&gt;
Output
  <title> </title> 
  (blank line)
  13
  <title>this is a test </title>
  string not found
```

Changing

```
$data = stristr(htmlspecialchars($data), htmlspecialchars($start));
```

to

```
$data = stristr(htmlspecialchars($data), $start);
```

and retesting.

```
Input  
  $start="<title>"
  $end="</title>"
Output
  (blank line)
  (blank line)
  7
  <title>this is a test </title>
  string not found

Input  
  $start="&lt;title&gt;"
  $end="&lt;/title&gt;"
Output
  <title> </title> 
  (blank line)
  13
  <title>this is a test </title>
  &gt;this is a test &lt;/title&gt;
```

I was expecting the last one to work.  I think it will on an actual web server because it seems that this online php tester inserts an extra 4 characters on the beginning of the string which keeps the last four from getting deleted.

I went and tried http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ next and the original strings without any htmlspecialchar functions worked exactly how I expected.  I used the same version in both of them.  Now I'm very confused.

Sorry for the long post.  If someone can explain to me how php parses html tags I would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: PHP doesn't parse HTML randomly. To actually parse HTML you'd want e.g. DomDocument or SimpleXML extensions. As you said, your post is quite long so I'm having a hard time actually working out what you're trying to get at.

Comment: php has no idea what html is. it's just text.but since you've commented out your `scrape_str`, you're actually doing your `=== false` test against the results of `substr()`, which will only return false on failure.

Comment: If php treats html as just text then why is it reading <title> </title> as special chatacters? Why is it not just treating it as a regular string?

Comment: Yeah this is pretty good - I've used it in the past.
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @RichardHousham OH GOODNESS SOURCEFORGE :melty_face_emoji:

Comment: Ok, I know sourceforge isn't that great compared with github, but I've used this package and it isn't that bad (although I think I recall a few tweeks!)

Answer (score 0):

This is not PHP parsing hence the lot of confusion you cause. You are just looking at string manipulation mostly.

So giving a bit more context to the output on my host the below code

```
$start = "<title>";
$end = "</title>";
$data = "<title>this is a test </title>";
echo "Showing Start: " . $start . " " . $end . " " . "<br>";
echo "Showing Data: " . $data . "<br>";
echo "Showing LEN Start: " . strlen($start) . "<br>";
echo "Showing Data special: " . htmlspecialchars($data) . "<br>";
$data = stristr(htmlspecialchars($data), htmlspecialchars($start));
echo "Showing Data stristr: " . $data . "<br>";
$data2 = stristr(htmlspecialchars($data), $start);
echo  "Showing Data2 stristr: " . $data2 . "<br>";
$data = substr(htmlspecialchars($data), strlen($start));
if($data===false){
    echo 'string not found';
}
else{
    echo  "Showing Data substr: " . $data . "<br>";
}
```

Will provide the following output:

```
Showing Start: 
Showing Data: 
Showing LEN Start: 7
Showing Data special: <title>this is a test </title>
Showing Data stristr: <title>this is a test </title>
Showing Data2 stristr: 
Showing Data substr: ;title&gt;this is a test &lt;/title&gt;
```

Explanation for each line above.

- The tag is being rendered by the browser
- The tag is being rendered by the browser
- Length of  is 7
- The tag is turned to ascii < and > the browser will show what those mean but do not render a tag.
- Since both tags are escaped you can find the whole string
- Since only data is escaped there is no match one is ascii < and > and the other has the title tag
- What you are working with is &amp;gt counting from 7 starting at 0 you get ; as your starting then take all of the remaining

fyi your if will never be false unless you do not have a string or your start where you have no index ie 70.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously has mistake in the code. You are re-writing the `$data` variable with multiple `=`  operations. Instead, use something like this:

```
.........
$data = "<title>this is a test </title>";
.........
$data1 = stristr(htmlspecialchars($data), htmlspecialchars($start));
$data2 = substr(htmlspecialchars($data), strlen($start));
.........
if (!$data1 && !$data2){
    echo 'not found';
}
......
```